# How can I force the bot to both wait for a specific event and continue to poll for events at the same time?

Tags: c#, steambot

I am using the [SteamBot](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot) application.

I have a command that is supposed to act when a specific event occurs. In this particular case, I, as the administrator, issue the command and the bot waits for a trade request and then continue on with my logic. What I can't figure out is how to make it wait until the trade request has occurred and then proceed.

Assume that I have issued the command and am now in the function that handles that command's behavior. This is a very simple example of what I'm trying to do.

```
private void giveItemsToUser()
{
    Bot.GetInventory();

    // Wait here

    var items = Trade.CurrentSchema.GetItemsByCraftingMaterial('hat');
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        added += Trade.AddAllItemsByDefindex(item.Defindex, amount);
    }

    Trade.SetReady(true);
    Trade.AcceptTrade();
}
```

In the `// Wait here` section, I want the bot to stop until the trade has started. Then, once it has started, it can proceed and add items as expected.

I've tried adding an `inTrade` (initialized to `false`) variable that is set to `true` in the `OnTradeInit` function and putting the bot to sleep until that is true.

```
while (!inTrade)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not in trade. Sleeping for 10 seconds.");
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

This, however, blocks the main thread and throws it into a tight loop. When it wakes up, it immediately checks if the variable is `true` and if not puts it back to sleep. There isn't time for the `HandleSteamMessage` function in `Bot.cs` to handle anything - even if the bot did receive an event while sleeping.

I've tried to use an `EventWaitHandle`, but that never seems to fire.

```
EventWaitHandle waitForInTrade = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "OnTradeRequest");
waitForInTrade.WaitOne(30000);
Console.WriteLine("In trade? " + inTrade.ToString());
```

This pauses the main thread for 30 seconds (due to the timeout passed in `WaitOne`) and then continues as expected. However, `inTrade` is still false, even if a trade request had been received. Since I'm not in a trade at that point, and subsequent code would be invalid.

So, what is the proper way to handle this type of interaction?

I cross posted this to the [/r/steambot](http://www.reddit.com/r/SteamBot/comments/1vdga4/how_can_i_force_the_bot_to_both_wait_for_a/) subreddit as well. I hope that is not a problem, especially since some of the comments on Github mentioned posting here for better assistance.

Comment: Side-note: The convention in C# is to start all methods with a capital letter.  Starting with a lowercase makes your code look extremely amateur-ish.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is fundamentally incorrect.  Steambot is event-based, so your logic needs to be based on responding to events in the event-handlers, not waiting for the events to occur.

So in other words, when the admin issues the `Give Items` command, you can't simply call a `GiveItemsToUser()` method.  Instead, you'll need something more like `QueueItemsToBeGivenToUser()` which creates a list of items to give to the user and stores it in a private variable.  Then when `OnTradeInit()` is called, you can check if that user has any items queued up, and if they do, add those items to the trade.